# Roblox SetDescription() On Roblox Starter Character Code

Tags: lua, roblox

So Im Tryna Make A Script That SetDrescription Of A Players Normal Character Than Put It On The Starter Character.

```
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local humanoid = script.Parent.Humanoid
local playerId = plr.UserId
humanoid:ApplyDescription(game.Players.GetHumanoidDescriptionFromUserId(playerId))
```

So Once I Tried Loading In With The Script It Did Not Set Description
[image]

Comment: Heyo, you need to share the code that you tried before we can help you

Comment: Yeah, I Just Edited the Post